# Can we just add [helpfile] to [documentation]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

According to tag excerpt of [documentation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/documentation):

> For questions regarding written documentation such as manuals, **help files**, policies, instructions, or guides.

But there exists [helpfile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/helpfile) too which in my opinion can be considered as the synonym of [documentation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/documentation) since I think *helpfile* is in *documentation* only.

But if the community wants to keep the tags separate, please consider posting an answer to this question with details.

Comment: Looking at a few questions tagged with `helpfile`, it seems to be incorrectly used. They should be retagged first, as the tag is being used to "request for help". For example, https://askubuntu.com/q/537979/8698 and https://askubuntu.com/q/596355/8698 anx there are a lot more as well.

Comment: @Dan Given that, I think we should probably delete this tag altogether

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the 55 questions currently tagged [helpfile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/helpfile), 13 of them are somewhat related to documentation.

The remainder are questions about all kinds of things, for example:

- [I can't open nautilus after executing rm -rf ~/.ddd/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122464/i-cant-open-nautilus-after-executing-rm-rf-ddd)
- [Can I sell a modified version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086887/can-i-sell-a-modified-version-of-ubuntu)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 not detecting HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990986/ubuntu-16-04-not-detecting-hdmi)

I think that people are using this tag when they want help with something.

I propose that we remove the tag as it seems very likely to be misused. The questions that are about documentation can be tagged [documentation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/documentation).